# Maximum number of characters in R data.table

Tags: r, dataset

Does anyone know if data.table in R have a limit to the number of characters/numbers in a string/numeric in a field?

Answer (score 1):

This question might be more suitable for StackOverflow than for CrossValidated, as it is a question of programming and not stats per se.

As to answer your question: As far as I'm aware the only limit on the size is dependent on the system resources available to R.
You can use the following code to see how much memory a certain object takes up

```
object.size(x)
```